# Why facebook share button shows article url on og:title graph in stead of the actual title?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jsf-2

I have as an example this page. 
http://www.kefet.com/content/article.html?langId=90&artLang=en
If you go to that link after logging to your facebook account and try to share the article,
on the title it shows you the url in stead of the title of the article. 
I went to check with facebook debugger, and obviously it said that I have the URL on

og:url          http://www.kefet.com/content/article.html?langId=90&artLang=en

og:title    http://www.kefet.com/content/article.html?langId=90&artLang=en

Yet when I go to see my source code of my page, I see all correct. Is there anyone that can help me and tell me what do I need to change in order to show the title of the article where it belongs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be facebook uses cache for OG tag.

You can use `sharer.php` as below :

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=your_url&p[images][0]=image_url&p[title]=your_title